# How to hide a tabpage in Experience Manager?

Tags: 2011, configuration, experience-manager

I am creating a GUI extension for Experience Manager in Tridion 2011 and would like to hide the "Preview Page" tab page. I have tried adding the following piece of code to the my extension config file with no result.

```
<ext:tabpages>
    <ext:remove>
        <ext:extension id="PreviewPage">
            <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="EditorView">
                    <ext:control id="MainToolbar" />
                </ext:view>
            </ext:apply>
        </ext:extension>                        
    </ext:remove>   
</ext:tabpages>
```

I know that I can hide the "Preview Page" tab using the following code in a script:

```js
var toolbar = $controls.getControl($("#MainToolbar"), "Tridion.Controls.RibbonToolbar");
var page = toolbar.getPageById("ReviewPage");
page.hide();
```

but I would prefer to use the config file if only I knew how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you mean hidding the tab "Preview" in the ribbontoolbar of the experience manager you have to add that code in the "ext:ribbontoolbars" section of the configuration file, like this:

```
        <ext:ribbontoolbars>
            <ext:remove>
                <ext:extension id="PreviewPage">
                    <ext:apply>
                        <ext:view name="EditorView">
                            <ext:control id="MainToolbar" />
                        </ext:view>
                    </ext:apply>
                </ext:extension>                        
            </ext:remove>   
        </ext:ribbontoolbars>
```